# How to copy table data and structure with Identity column and its value to another table in the same db(just change table name)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have trouble in copying table data and structure to another table since I want to keep the `Id` column of Identity column and keep its oridinal value instead of starting from 1

I use below sql to insert all data except the `ID` column from `MY_TABLE` to `MY_TABLE_NEW` since it has error saying that

> Only when the column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON, an explicit value can be specified for the identity column in the table'My_TABLE_NEW'.

But I have set it like below SQL:

```
IF NOT EXISTS (select * from sys.objects where name = 'My_TABLE_NEW')
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[My_TABLE_NEW]
    (
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [OBJECT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
        [YEAR_MONTH] [int] NOT NULL,
            
        CONSTRAINT [PK_My_TABLE_NEW] 
            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                        WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                              IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                              ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
END
GO

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'My_TABLE_NEW')
BEGIN
    SET IDENTITY_INSERT My_TABLE_NEW ON

    INSERT INTO My_TABLE_NEW
        SELECT [ID]
               ,[OBJECT_ID]
              ,[YEAR_MONTH]
        FROM My_TABLE

   SET IDENTITY_INSERT My_TABLE_NEW OFF
END
GO
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to create a copy of an existing table or just rename an existing table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try your insert with the column names:

```
INSERT INTO My_TABLE_NEW ([ID], [OBJECT_ID], [YEAR_MONTH])
        SELECT [ID]
               ,[OBJECT_ID]
              ,[YEAR_MONTH]             
        FROM My_TABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15):

> When an existing identity column is selected into a new table, the new column inherits the IDENTITY property, unless one of the following conditions is true:
>
> ```
> The SELECT statement contains a join, GROUP BY clause, or aggregate function.
>
> Multiple SELECT statements are joined by using UNION.
>
> The identity column is listed more than one time in the select list.
>
> The identity column is part of an expression.
>
> The identity column is from a remote data source.
> ```

That means you can copy the table with `SELECT INTO` while retaining the identity column and can just add the PK after.

```
SELECT *
INTO My_TABLE_NEW
FROM My_TABLE
```

Here is a demo with [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8b3d55040386b6d7ddcafd76abae30e8).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in tool `sp_rename` for this, as long as you are just renaming the table not trying to create a copy of it.

```
EXEC sp_rename 'My_TABLE', 'My_TABLE_NEW'
GO;
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-rename-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

If you want to create a copy, then you just have to do the following:

```
SELECT *
INTO My_TABLE_NEW
FROM My_TABLE
```

Note: If you do this, you will have to re-add any key constraints, computed value columns, etc.